# Script to add protection status registry key

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script in PowerShell with the following PS command and create a Registry key in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE` with the results of "Protection Status: Protection Off or On".

```
PS> manage-bde -status -cn localhost
```

See output sample below:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Computer Name: localhost

Disk volumes that can be protected with
BitLocker Drive Encryption:
Volume C: [OSD]
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 232.59 GB
    BitLocker Version:    Windows 7
    Conversion Status:    Encryption in Progress
    Percentage Encrypted: 45%
    Encryption Method:    AES 128 with Diffuser
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: None
    Key Protectors:
        TPM
```

Comment: You might get better results if you can demonstrate that you've researched this and show some code that you've tried.  Requests for code to be written without showing any effort are often ignored.

Comment: The only I have so far is this one : Set-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE -Value "Protection On"  , I'm trying to figure out how to add the string value "Protection On" in the script.

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether protection is on or off:

```
[string]$ProtectionStatus

if(@((manage-bde -status -cn localhost) -like '*Protection On').Count -gt 0){
    $ProtectionStatus = "Protection On"
}

else {$ProtectionStatus = "Protection Off"}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do--I'm assuming FVE is a registry key (displayed as a folder in Registry Editor).  To add a new string value of "MyTestEntry" with data that was put into the $ProtectionStatus variable above:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE -Name MyTestEntry -PropertyType String -Value "$ProtectionStatus"
```

See [Working with Registry Entries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315394.aspx)

If this doesn't help you, please carefully explain what you want.  If you just need the command to create a string registry entry, then the output from the manage-bde command is irrelevant.  If you are somehow wanting to use the output from that command to use in the command to create the registry entry, then you need to be very clear about what you want to parse out and exactly what it looks like after it's in the registry.

Comment: I want to create a register key base on the results of the following Powershell command:

PS> manage-bde -status -cn localhost
Disk volumes that can be protected with
 
    Encryption Method:    AES 128 with Diffuser
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    
So the script will need to extract the string in the line called : Protection Status: Protection Off/On and create a variable called for i.e : $ProtectionStatus and then add the register key with the command :

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE -Name MyTestEntry -PropertyType String -Value "$ProtectionStatus"